# How to customize Bootstrap Stylus variables using my own .styl file out of the bootstrap stylus folder?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, stylus

I'm trying to <strike>customize</strike> **remove border radius** of Bootstrap Stylus.
I'm importing the stylus main file called index.styl into my own style.styl, then, I'm importing custom-variables.styl that is the same of variables.styl used by Bootstrap Stylus, but when I use grunt-contrib-stylus it never use custom variables values.

Comment: You're importing customised variables *after* the Bootstrap stylesheet? IIRC, this would work in LESS, but Stylus requires the variables to be defined before going over the stylesheet. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It works perfectly.

Comment: You can use Bootstrap port to Stylus  https://github.com/Acquisio/bootstrap-stylus with single variables file for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to import my variables AFTER my style.styl file and it didn't work.
Now, it's solved, I'm importing the variables BEFORE style.styl.